# how to pass control to grails error page if the exception occurs in controller?

Tags: grails, groovy

I have one method in controller which will be called when user clicks on link

```
  <g:link controller="reporting" action="dataCenterNetworkReports">
    <g:message code="reports.data.center.network"/>
  </g:link>
```

that method will be getting response from the webservice. Now my question is if some thing goes wrog in WS and returns an error I need to pass the control and display the error message. how to display common error page when some thing goes wrong and comes to catch block.

Answer (score 0):

Grails have the default error gsp in `views/error.gsp`. If you look the code this needs an exception, so something like this I think should be enough (not tested):

**Your controller method**

```
def dataCenterNetworkReports() {
   String view = "myDefaultView"
   def model = [:]
   try {
     //call webservice
   }catch(e) {
     view = '/error' 
     model.exception = e
   }
   //when occur some exception view will be /error
   render(view: view, model: model)     
}
```

But if you need to show some custom layout, then [flash object](http://www.grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Controllers/flash.html) can be your choice.

Comment: Your option sounds good but what I want to do is replce the current page being displayed by the error page. current page has some tepletes displayed already while WS call is running at the back.I have created default error page to test but it is not showing up.

Comment: Can you post more code? This is a plugin or grails app? The error page already exists in grails apps.